# Angular and node.js nginx deployment on CentOS

Tags: node.js, angular, nginx

I have Nginx webserver installed on CentOS. I would like to deploy Angular 6 Apps and node.js server on this Nginx webserver. My build angular app is in /usr/share/nginx/html and node.js server is running on localhost:8080.
This is my config file:

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       443 ssl default_server;
    ssl_certificate "/home/intern/AutoScan/AutoScan_api/ssl/autoscan.crt";
    ssl_certificate_key "/home/intern/AutoScan/AutoScan_api/ssl/autoscan.pem";

    root /user/share/nginx/html/www;
    server_name  _;
    # Load configuration files for the default server block.

    location /{

            proxy_pass https://localhost:8080;
            proxy_redirect          off;
            proxy_set_header Host $https-host;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}
```

Currently i can't open Angular Application. If i change  location server for example to /server it partially works, I mean angular application works but i can't make requests, because invalid paths.

Do you have any idea, what should I do?

Comment: What is the `<base>` tag value in your index.html ? it should be `/user/share/nginx/html/www`

Comment: I didn't have but after this change, it still not working properly

Comment: Did you add the base tag?

Comment: Yes <base href="/user/share/nginx/html/www">